# Any pointers for sending data from solr server to sap Hana using java

Tags: jdbc, solr, solrj, hana

I have some (1.8 mill documents)  stored in the Solr server, I want to do some minimal query stuff in java (using Solrj API) and send the processed data in a table in a sap hana instance . Can anyone please help me ,how can it be possible via java.

Comment: your question is very unspecific and lacks information.

Comment: @stb i want to move data from solr server to hana studio using java.Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `Hana studio` is the management software for a `hana` database (based on `eclipse`). Do you need to achieve this using java? I'm not familiar with `solr`, but if this is a one-time process, you may be able to export the data by hand and import it a `hana schema`.

Comment: @stb can you please let me know why you downvote it.I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SAP HANA supports JDBC you can take whatever data you have in JAVA and run SQL commands to insert them into SAP HANA like you would with any other JDBC supporting DBMS.
This is an answer as specific as possible given your question.